# Compare two date from JSON result in RecyclerView

Tags: android, datetime, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I got a **recyclerView** that will populate according to a JSON result using **databinding**, what i want to do is to **check/compare the start date & expired date** to see is the "Deals" is expired (if expired a textview with text "DEALS EXPIRED" will appear)

```
"DealsPageInfo": [
    {
      "DisplayName": "string",
      "StartDate": "2018-04-27T03:06:18.890Z",
      "ExpiredDate": "2018-04-27T03:06:18.890Z",
      "Url": "string",
      "ImageUrl": "string",
      "ShortDescription": "string"
    }
```

Here is some question from me:

 * should i use DATE / String to store the object?

 * where should i perform this action? under my fragment / adapter?

 Appreciate if any source / example provided.

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/list_offers_startDate"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
      android:text="@{offers.StartDate}"
      android:textColor="@color/colorGrayText"
      android:textSize="@dimen/list_fontsize"
      />

 <TextView
      android:id="@+id/list_offers_endDate"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
      android:text="@{offers.ExpiredDate}"
      android:textColor="@color/colorGrayText"
      android:textSize="@dimen/form_fontsize"
      />
```

Comment: [refer this ans i hope it will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40051677/2794507)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to compare dates in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774871/best-way-to-compare-dates-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** where should i perform this action? under my fragment / adapter?** 
perform this in onBindViewHolder of your adapter,

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position){
        if (isDateExpired(listItems.get(position).getStartDate(),listItems.get(position).getEndDate())){
            viewHolder.dealsExpiredtextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            viewHolder.dealsExpiredtextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }
```

add this method in your adapter,

```
public boolean isDateExpired(String startDate, String endDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    boolean b = false;
    try {
        if (dfDate.parse(startDate).before(dfDate.parse(endDate))) {
            return true;  // If start date is before end date.
        } else if (dfDate.parse(startDate).equals(dfDate.parse(endDate))) {
            return false;  // If two dates are equal.
        } else {
            return false; // If start date is after the end date.
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: the isDateExpired has no any return item, and if i remove the try and replace with throw exception, it seems like not working.

Comment: Will the date format impact on this? as my JSON result format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh-mm-ss"

Comment: isDateExpired is returning a boolean value. Use try catch only

Comment: i'm using the isDateExpired function, but it error for missing return statement.

Comment: can i replace the start date with new Date() if i want to compare with current date?

Comment: yes. pass the two dates which you want to compare with.

Comment: check the updated answer. I think your date is not getting parsed properly.

Comment: Thanks @hasan_shaikh, this should be work fine, just some problem on my code. it return all same result in recycle view. might due to the date compare by parsing the current date. "if (new Date().after(dfDate.parse(endDate)))"...still figuring

Comment: @Shawn.Y did you got the proper solution? If yes then how did you solve the same result in recycler view?

Answer (score 0):

> should i use DATE / String to store the object?

Yes you have to save both values in Date or string.

> where should i perform this action? under my fragment / adapter?

You have to perform this function in your adapter. while populate data to view.

compare date :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date StartDate= sdf.parse(StartDate);
Date ExpiredDate= sdf.parse(ExpiredDate);
if (StartDate.after(ExpiredDate)) {
    //create your logic here
}
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: Thanks! this helps although still figuring how to use it under my code.

Comment: you already accept other's ans still figuring how to use. strange!!

Comment: The accepted answer is working, but still minor changes to fit into my code

Answer (score 0):

You can use timestamp to do this kind of time checking thing. Send start and end timestamp in your json. And you can do this in your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you should use `Date` to represent start date and whatever other date you have, it makes more sense.

I don't think your Adapter/View is the best place do to this conversion. You should either have your parser do that for you OR you could do some post processing on your `List` of objects once they have been fetched from the network. Preferably even on a background thread.

Parsing those `String`s to `Date`s in your `Adapter` is kind of wasteful and might make your `RecyclerView` a bit laggy. It will cause for repeated calculations of the same values and possibly a lengthy date parsing on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly if you want change textview text to "DEALS EXPIRED" you should perform action under your adapter.
- If you don't want parse string again you can store date as Date object.

You can parse your date like this.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-04-27T03:06:18.890Z" );
Date date = java.util.Date.from( instant );
if ( Calendar.getInstance().after( date ) ) {
    // if this statement is true deal is expired.
}
```

Comment: it will had a text view "DEALS EXPIRED" creates in xml, and set the visibility "gone", it should change the visibility as "Visible" after checking